# Android SDK Lint tool Ignoring NewAPI warnings

Tags: android, android-sdk-tools, android-lint

I am running the Lint tool from Eclipse(Android SDK).

My settings are default and NewApi is set up as Error in my Android Lint Settings
However, when I run Lint (by `Package Explorer > Android Tools > Run Lint: Check for Common Errors`.), It seems to ignore the fact that I have used API methods higher than the `android:minSdkVersion` in my manifest XML.

What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE:**

I tried to do the check by Lint command line tool by:

`lint "C:\Android\workspace\MyProject"`   -- still didnot show the newAPI errors

However when I did  the link check specifically for newAPI:

`lint --check NewApi "C:\Android\workspace\MyProject"`      --- showed the expected errors

Why are NewApi errors not pointed by default?

Comment: Can you paste the code where you have used NewAPIs?

Comment: Turns out that this is a bug. Check this [link](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=56427).

Comment: That bug is closed now. But I still see the issue. 

Using Android Studio 3.0.1, I ran Lint. Please let me know in which section of the results this check is listed. I used to get the warning as a compile time error before in java file itself. Now, it did not show up. 

E.g: Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.privacy_policy_name)) is introduced in API 24. minSdkVersion is 16 in build.gradle file. No error was shown in java file where this was written. Tried to find the error in lint results. I am not able to find the section where this kind of error is specified

Comment: Sorry, when I use the correct method introduced in API 24, I get the warning:
Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.privacy_policy_name), 0);

But, the deprecation warning for using Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.privacy_policy_name)) was NOT shown. It's a minor issue anyways.

Comment: For Android Studio users. Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49357147/8942811).