# Android Lint limitations?

Tags: android, lint

I recently discovered a fatal error in my android app running on Android version 10 from this line:

```
((Button)alert.findViewById(android.R.id.button1)).setAllCaps(true);
```

I have set `android:minSdkVersion="9"` in `AndroidManifest.xml`.

The root cause was android.widget.Button inherits from android.widget.TextView and the setAllCaps method was implemented in API level 14.
**Reference:** https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setAllCaps(boolean)

So my question is **why can't I get lint to discover this class of error?** 
I would presume that `lint --check NewApi .` would find this kind of issue.

Is it because the dialog which has this button is dynamically created just before this code?

Is there anything I can do to help lint prevent this class of error? In a perfect world I would like warnings to be thrown for any methods called from SDK versions higher than `minSdk`.

Comment: If you only need a method off `TextView` then just cast to `TextView` not `Button`

Comment: Its a bug. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21614007/android-sdk-lint-tool-ignoring-newapi-warnings/21752114#21752114