# Why android studio is not giving newapi warning?

Tags: android, android-studio

My project's minSdkVersion is 15, targetSdkVersion 26 and compileSdkVersion 27. I'm using the latest android studio. But when I call `isDestroyed()` inside activity android studio is not giving `newApi` warning. `isDestroyed()` was added in api level 17. My activity extends `AppCompatActivity`. My question is similar to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42974686/android-studio-not-giving-warning-under-certain-conditions), but it doesn't have answer.

Comment: i's it problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to File --> Settings --> Editor --> Inspection --> Android --> Lint --> Correctness and check `Calling new methods on older versions`.